# How to not hardcode HTML value attributes (with spaces) in R

Tags: html, css, r

Following on from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341849/a-way-to-not-hardcode-items-in-css-with-r-shiny-app). I have a function in R which generates some CSS code.

```r
CSS <- function(values, colors){
  template <- "
.option[data-value=%s], .item[data-value=%s]{
  background: %s !important;
  color: white !important;
}"
  paste0(
    apply(cbind(values, colors), 1, function(vc){
      sprintf(template, vc[1], vc[1], vc[2])
    }),
    collapse = "\n"
  )
}
```

For example, `CSS(c("a","b","c"), c("red", "green", "blue"))` generates

```r
.option[data-value=a], .item[data-value=a]{
  background: red !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.option[data-value=b], .item[data-value=b]{
  background: green !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.option[data-value=c], .item[data-value=c]{
  background: blue !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

However, if my values are `c("a 1","b 2","c 3 3")`

and I execute `CSS(c("a 1","b 2","c 3 3"), c("red", "green", "blue"))` the CSS does not recognise the space between each element, for each character in the character vector. So `"a 1"` is not recognised, it is read as `"a"`, and `"b 2"` is read as `"b"` etc.

I know I need to wrap each character in quotes, as otherwise the space will just become an attribute separator and everything after spaces will be seen as element attributes. But how do I do this within the above function without having to hardcode it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  template <- "
.option[data-value='%s'], .item[data-value='%s']{
  background: %s !important;
  color: white !important;
}"
```